# Textfield still strips last character

Tags: nativescript

Just upgraded to Sonoma to run Xcode 15 for SDK 17.2. All Nativescript apps that previously worked that used a Textfield are now broken. Textfield Strips last character. Running Nativescript 8.6.5 same issue with 8.6.1. TextView works for not removing last character. Build in Xcode for M1 Arm64 and issue is not present, but makes development in Nativescript troublesome.

Comment: I also have the same problem on an Intel Mac.  The odd thing is, it only cuts off the last character in the simulators. On a real device it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem where the simulator cuts off the last character of `TextField`'s but real devices work fine. I did some searching and found the below:

> This issue only happens on x86 builds on the iOS simulator on iOS 16.4+ (xcode 14.3+). It's not related to NativeScript itself (or angular).
>
> Unfortunately this is something only apple can properly fix:
> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727715
> [NativeScript/NativeScript#10267](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/10267#issuecomment-1593015385)
>
> [ref](https://github.com/NativeScript/angular/issues/119#issuecomment-1610115999)

**The good news is that it appears to be fixed in Xcode 15.3!**

---

##### Update

So [@nativescript/ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/ios) [v8.6.4](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios/releases/tag/v8.6.4) was released today, which works with the new Xcode 15.3, and I can confirm that Apple has fixed the issue! I tested using Xcode 15.3 with a simulator running iOS 17.4, and found that the last character of `TextField`'s is no longer is cutoff!

Make sure you also update *Command Line Tools for Xcode* to v15.3.